# Fatal Error - MongoDB ReplicaSet Node Starting Issue in - Docker desktop

Tags: mongodb, fatal-error, replicaset, docker-desktop

2021-02-17T12:54:01.824+0000 W STORAGE [initandlisten] Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version.

2021-02-17T12:54:01.824+0000 F STORAGE [initandlisten] Reason: 1: Operation not permitted

2021-02-17T12:54:01.824+0000 F - [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28595 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp 925

2021-02-17T12:54:01.824+0000 F - [initandlisten] \n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n

Docker Compose version is "3"
I am using Docker Desktop and started 3 nodes using yml file in a cluster for mongo replicaset.  After i stopped the primary node, 2nd secondary node elected as primary.
Then i tried to start the stopped node1 in docker desktop containers, i not able to start it again.
It show the fatal error and asks to delete the mongodb-27017.sock file

Please help ?

Yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  Node1:
    image: "mongo:4.2"
    ports: 
      - "27017:27017"
    extra_hosts:
      - "<my_ipaddress>:0.0.0.0"
    volumes:
      - ./Node1/data:/data/db
    networks:
      - mongocluster
    command: mongod --replSet rp1 --port 27017

  Node2:
    image: "mongo:4.2"
    ports: 
      - "27018:27018"
    extra_hosts:
      - "<my_ipaddress>:0.0.0.0"
    volumes:
      - ./Node2/data:/data/db
    networks:
      - mongocluster
    command: mongod --replSet rp1 --port 27018
    depends_on:
      - Node1

  Node3:
    image: "mongo:4.2"
    ports: 
      - "27019:27019"
    extra_hosts:
      - "<my_ipaddress>:0.0.0.0"
    volumes:
      - ./Node3/data:/data/db
    networks:
      - mongocluster
    command: mongod --replSet rp1 --port 27019
    depends_on:
      - Node2
  
networks:
  mongocluster:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: This is a nasty one. And mostly happens when your network/disk crashes or you do a unclean shutdown. You may try to execute [restore actions](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/restore-sharded-cluster/).

Comment: i stopped using : docker stop <my_continer>   and in docker desktop ui also.  if not what is way to start and stop the container without this fatal error.